# What happens if the Input voltage and the output voltage are same in a boost converter?

Tags: voltage, current, dc-dc-converter, buck, boost

I'd just like to know what would happen if the Input voltage and the output voltage are same in a boost converter. I have a feel that it might not work.

But would like to understand the effects that will happen on the inductor and the switching MOSFET.

This [converter](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/20005173b.pdf) is an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general anything can happen, it's up to the chip.

Your data sheet specifically says it is unstable if Vin > Vout.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It only says greater. What will happen if Vin = Vout?

Comment: Why do you need to worry about a mathematical boundary case when dealing with real world electronics? Do you think output will be 5.000000V and it will work as long as input is up to 4.999999V for example?

Comment: No no. Just curious to understand what will happen? Would like to know how the inductor and MOSFET would behave if Vin = Vout.

Comment: That is a hypothetical question irrelevant for this chip. But for an ideal mathematical model with no losses, the switching duty cycle will be 0% when Vin equals Vout.